# Expected overlap area of square with rectangles is greater than expected overlap of randomly picked rectangle with other rectangle and square

Tags: calculus, geometry

I am trying to prove the following (if it is true or false, I am not sure but I want to prove in either case.)

Let R be the set of all rectangles with a center point c and area a and r belongs to R. Assuming that all rectangles are equally likely, the expected area of overlap between R and r is maximized when r is a square.

(All rectangles and the square is constructed from same center and have same area a as given. All rectangle are axis parallel. With equally likely, it is meant that if there is rectangle r along x axis, then we can flip this rectangle by 90 degree to get another rectangle. So if one rectangle occurs, the flip version of the same rectangle also occurs.)

Thanks

Comment: As far as proving it goes, it'd be simpler with a finite collection of rectangles (that still satisfy "symmetry" in their ratio) or restrict the range of the admissible ratio. Strictly speaking in such infinite collection you should specify the pdf function, since we can't make it uniform when every ratio is possible. And dealing with a general pdf that only satisfy the property you describe makes the proof a tad more annoying. But the result is most likely true.

Comment: It is unclear to me what "area of overlap" actually means. If rectangle $A$ overlaps rectangle $B$, giving overlap area $b$, and $A$ overlaps $C$, giving overlap area $c$, is the "area of overlap" (1) the sum $b + c$ or (2) the area that the two overlaps have in common or (3) the sum minus the area they have in common?

Comment: Also, are you considering only a subset of $R$? Because if all possible rectangles are included, the area of overlap for *any* rectangle in the three cases I gave above would be (1) infinite (2) 0 and (3) a.

Comment: @Jens We're looking at the *expected* overlap area, assuming you only have the two rectangles $B$ and $C$, the value to maximise is the mean between $b$ and $c$, so $(b+c)/2$.

Answer (score 0):

Tl;dr : the property is in general false, but for the suggested distribution it is true.

#### Parameterization of the family

For a rectangle of $x$-width $w$ and $y$-height $h$, let's denote its aspect ratio by $\rho=\frac wh$. Rectangles $r\in R$ are fully defined by their ratio $\rho$,
$$
R=\left\{\text{rectangle of ratio $\rho$}  \mid h=\sqrt{\frac A\rho},\ w=\rho h \right\}
$$
Given some rectangle in $R$ of ratio $\rho_0$, its overlap with another rectangle of $R$ with ratio $\rho$ is
$f(\rho,\rho_0)=\min\{ w;\ w_0\}\times\min\{ h;\ h_0\}$.
Assuming that $\rho\le \rho_0$ and using the above formula we end up with
$f(\rho\le\rho_0)=A\sqrt{\frac\rho{\rho_0}}$.
In the other case we have
$f(\rho\ge\rho_0)=A\sqrt{\frac{\rho_0}\rho}$.

#### The pdf

From your description of the mean you want, you have some pdf function on $\rho$ that satisfies something like
$\forall 1\le \rho_1\le\rho_2$,
$$
\int_{\rho_1}^{\rho_2}\operatorname{pdf}(\rho)\,d\rho=
\int_{1/\rho_2}^{1/\rho_1}\operatorname{pdf}(\rho)\,d\rho
$$
If you perform the change of variable $X=\frac 1\rho$ on the right hand side you get
$$
\int_{\rho_1}^{\rho_2}\operatorname{pdf}(\rho)\,d\rho=
\int_{\rho_2}^{\rho_1}\operatorname{pdf}\left(\frac 1X\right)\,\frac{-dX}{X^2}=
\int_{\rho_1}^{\rho_2}\frac{\operatorname{pdf}\left(\frac 1X\right)}{X^2}\,dX
$$
so you have $\rho^2\operatorname{pdf}(\rho)=\operatorname{pdf}(1/\rho)$.
If you specify the pdf for $\rho$ values greater than $1$, it is fully specified (and conversely if you give the pdf for $\rho\le 1$).

For short, whenever taking the inverse would be interesting in an integration we have
$$
\int_{\rho_1}^{\rho_2} f(\rho)\operatorname{pdf}(\rho)\,d\rho=
\int_{1/\rho_2}^{1/\rho_1} f\left(\frac 1\rho\right)\operatorname{pdf}(\rho)\,d\rho
$$

#### Uniform(?) distribution on bounded interval

Assuming you restrict the range of admissible ratio, so we can have a
pseudo uniform distribution. Let $\rho_\text{max}$ be the maximum ratio. For $\rho>\rho_\text{max}$ we have $\operatorname{pdf}(\rho)=0$, which also implies
that for $\rho< 1/\rho_\text{max}$, $\operatorname{pdf}(\rho)=0$.

Consider the top right corner of a rectangle. As its ratio goes from $1/\rho_\text{max}$ to $\rho_\text{max}$, this corner traces a portion of a hyperbola.
The "uniform distribution" that matches what you want to do, as far as I understand, is that any point on that hyperbola is equally likely to yield a rectangle in the family. This unfortunately does not result in a uniform distribution in the ratio/width/height, but a uniform distribution in the curvilinear abscissa
$$
s(\rho)=\frac {\sqrt{A}}2 \int_{1/\rho_\text{max}}^\rho
  \sqrt{\frac{1+u^2}{u^3}}\,du
$$
To get this expression, note that the hyperbola can be parameterised in $\rho$ as the set of points
$\left\{ \left(\sqrt{\rho A},\ \sqrt{\frac A\rho}\right) \right\}$, the tangent vector is then
$
\mathbf N(\rho)=\sqrt{A}\left( \frac 1{2\sqrt\rho},\ \frac{-1}{2\rho\sqrt\rho} \right)
$
and by definition
$
ds = \left\| \mathbf N(\rho) \right\|\,d\rho
=\frac{\sqrt A}2\sqrt{\frac{1+\rho^2}{\rho^3}}\,d\rho
$.

Consider a specific rectangle with ratio $\rho_0$ in the range $1/\rho_\text{max}$ and $\rho_\text{max}$.

\begin{align*}
\mathbb E[\operatorname{overlap}]
&=\int_{s=0}^{s_\text{max}} \frac{f(s,s_0)}{s_\text{max}} \,ds\\
&=\int_{1/\rho_\text{max}}^{\rho_\text{max}} 
  \frac{f(\rho,\rho_0)}{s_\text{max}}\times \frac{\sqrt{A}}2
  \sqrt{\frac{1+\rho^2}{\rho^3}}\,d\rho\\
\frac{2s_\text{max}}{\sqrt A}\mathbb E[\operatorname{overlap}]
&=\int_{1/\rho_\text{max}}^{\rho_0}A\sqrt{\frac{\rho}{\rho_0}}
  \sqrt{\frac{1+\rho^2}{\rho^3}}\,d\rho
  +\int_{\rho_0}^{\rho_\text{max}}A\sqrt{\frac{\rho_0}{\rho}}
  \sqrt{\frac{1+\rho^2}{\rho^3}}\,d\rho\\
&= \frac{A}{\sqrt{\rho_0}} \int_{1/\rho_\text{max}}^{\rho_0}
  \sqrt{\frac{1+\rho^2}{\rho^2}}\,d\rho
  +A\sqrt{\rho_0} \int_{1/\rho_\text{max}}^{1/\rho_0}
  \sqrt{\frac{1+\rho^2}{\rho^2}}\,d\rho\\
\end{align*}

We derive with respect to $\rho_0$
\begin{align*}
\frac{2s_\text{max}}{A\sqrt A}\frac\partial{\partial\rho_0}
\mathbb E[\operatorname{overlap}]
&=\frac{-1}{2\rho_0\sqrt{\rho_0}} \int_{1/\rho_\text{max}}^{\rho_0}
  \sqrt{\frac{1+\rho^2}{\rho^2}}\,d\rho
  +\frac{1}{\sqrt{\rho_0}} \sqrt{\frac{1+\rho_0^2}{\rho_0^2}}\\
  &\qquad
  +\frac 1{2\sqrt{\rho_0}} \int_{1/\rho_\text{max}}^{1/\rho_0}
  \sqrt{\frac{1+\rho^2}{\rho^2}}\,d\rho
  +\sqrt{\rho_0} \times \frac{-1}{\rho_0^2} \times \sqrt{1+\rho_0^2} \\
\frac{4s_\text{max}\sqrt{\rho_0}}{A\sqrt A}\frac\partial{\partial\rho_0}
\mathbb E[\operatorname{overlap}]
&= \int_{1/\rho_\text{max}}^{1/\rho_0}
  \sqrt{\frac{1+\rho^2}{\rho^2}}\,d\rho
  -\frac{1}{\rho_0} \int_{1/\rho_\text{max}}^{\rho_0}
  \sqrt{\frac{1+\rho^2}{\rho^2}}\,d\rho\\
&= \int_{\rho_0}^{\rho_\text{max}} \frac{\sqrt{1+\rho^2}}{\rho^2}\,d\rho
  -\frac 1{\rho_0} \int_{1/\rho_0}^{\rho_\text{max}}
  \frac{\sqrt{1+\rho^2}}{\rho^2}\,d\rho \\
&= \left[ -\frac{\sqrt{1+\rho^2}}{\rho} \right]_{\rho_0}^{\rho_\text{max}}
  +\int_{\rho_0}^{\rho_\text{max}} \frac 1{\sqrt{1+\rho^2}}\,d\rho\\
  &\qquad
  +\frac 1{\rho_0} 
  \left[\frac{\sqrt{1+\rho^2}}{\rho}\right]_{1/\rho_0}^{\rho_\text{max}}
  -\frac 1{\rho_0} 
  \int_{1/\rho_0}^{\rho_\text{max}} \frac 1{\sqrt{1+\rho^2}}\,d\rho\\
&= \frac{\sqrt{1+\rho_0^2}}{\rho_0}
  -\frac{\sqrt{1+\rho_\text{max}^2}}{\rho_\text{max}}
  +\frac 1{\rho_0}\left(
  \frac{\sqrt{1+\rho_\text{max}^2}}{\rho_\text{max}}
  -\rho_0 \sqrt{\frac{1+\rho_0^2}{\rho_0^2}}
  \right)\\
  &\qquad +\big[\text{arsinh}(\rho) \big]_{\rho_0}^{\rho_\text{max}}
  -\frac 1{\rho_0}
  \big[\text{arsinh}(\rho) \big]_{1/\rho_0}^{\rho_\text{max}}\\
&=\left( \frac 1{\rho_0} -1\right)
  \left( \frac{\sqrt{1+\rho_\text{max}^2}}{\rho_\text{max}}
  -\text{arsinh}(\rho_\text{max}) \right)
  +\text{arsinh}(\rho_0) -\frac{\text{arsinh}(1/\rho_0)}{\rho_0}\\
&=\frac{-1}{\rho_0}\left( \text{arsinh}(1/\rho_0) -C \right)
  +\left( \text{arsinh}(\rho_0) -C\right)
\end{align*}

Where
$C=\frac{\sqrt{1+\rho_\text{max}^2}}{\rho_\text{max}}
  -\text{arsinh}(\rho_\text{max})$.
Let the function $g$ be defined by
$g(t)=\text{arsinh}(t)-C$, it is strictly increasing.
The sign of the derivative is given by the sign of
$g(\rho_0) -\frac 1{\rho_0} g(1/\rho_0)$.

When $\rho_0<1$, we have $\rho_0<1<\frac 1{\rho_0}$ and
$g(\rho_0)< g(1/\rho_0)< \frac 1{\rho_0}g(1/\rho_0)$.
Hence the derivative is positive.
When $\rho_0>1$, we have $g(\rho_0)> g(1/\rho_0) > \frac 1{\rho_0}g(1/\rho_0)$ and the derivative is negative.
Within the range $1/\rho_\text{max}$ to $\rho_\text{max}$, $\rho_0=1$ is thus a local maxima. We should also check outside the range, but the computation is simpler in those cases. Anyway, the square yields the global maxima.

#### Computation - counter-exemple (general case)

Edit: changed to something else completely because the previous was false.

Assume you take some pdf function that is null around values of 1. Let's say there exists some $X>1$ such that for all $\frac 1X\le \rho\le X$,
$\operatorname{pdf}(\rho) = 0$. In words, rectangles that look like a square have little probability of occuring, whereas skewed rectangles occur frequently.
Now say you pick a rectangle whose ratio is close to a square, specifically 
its ratio $\rho_0$ is between $1/X$ and $X$.

\begin{align*}
\mathbb E[\operatorname{overlap}]
&=\int_0^{+\infty}f(\rho,\rho_0)\operatorname{pdf}(\rho)\,d\rho\\
&=\int_0^{1/X}f(\rho\le\rho_0)\operatorname{pdf}(\rho)\,d\rho  
 +\int_{1/X}^{X}f(\rho,\rho_0)\operatorname{pdf}(\rho)\,d\rho
 +\int_{X}^{+\infty}f(\rho\ge\rho_0)\operatorname{pdf}(\rho)\,d\rho\\
&=\int_0^{1/X}A\sqrt{\frac\rho{\rho_0}}\operatorname{pdf}(\rho)\,d\rho  
 +0
 +\int_{X}^{+\infty}A\sqrt{\frac{\rho_0}\rho}\operatorname{pdf}(\rho)\,d\rho\\
&=\int_0^{1/X}A\sqrt{\frac\rho{\rho_0}}\operatorname{pdf}(\rho)\,d\rho  
 +\int_{0}^{1/X}A\sqrt{\rho_0\rho}\operatorname{pdf}(\rho)\,d\rho\\
&=\left(\frac 1{\sqrt{\rho_0}}+\sqrt{\rho_0}\right)
  \times\int_0^{1/X}A\sqrt{\rho}\operatorname{pdf}(\rho)\,d\rho  \\
&=\left(\frac 1{\sqrt{\rho_0}}+\sqrt{\rho_0}\right)\times C
\end{align*}

Where $C$ is a constant independent from $\rho_0$. We then just have to study the variations of 
$\rho_0 \mapsto \sqrt{\rho_0}+1/\sqrt{\rho_0}$ which clearly isn't maximum for $\rho_0=1$ (the square case).
The above may suggest that the maximum is reached for $\rho_0=0$ or $+\infty$, but that's not the case. The formula is only valid for
$\frac 1X\le\rho_0\le X$ so we need to recompute it when we get out of these bounds.

#### Discussion

To put some sense into the result, just imagine every rectangles in the family $R$ is very skewed. If you pick a square it will overlap very little of every rectangles. On the other hand if you pick a rectangle whose skew agrees with (half of) the family, you will cover a lot of area (and compensate for the fact you ignore half of the family).

Comment: Thanks N. Bach.  In the last part of the proof where you took, g be the increasing function and showed that differentiation of expectation with ρ0 is >= 0, is bit unclear to me. To be more specific, g(ρ0)≤ρ0g(1/ρ0) of given inequality, I am unable to understand why it will be that. If you can explain little more of this part, it will be great.  Also, if you can given idea on how to show differentiation of expectation <= 0  for ρ≥1  .. Thanks again!

Comment: @sanket Re-reading it, looks like a mistake on my part, so my proof is wrong. Gonna check if I have some way out of this.

Comment: @sanket I've updated my answer... trying to prove something false has always been a good exercise in futility!

Comment: The counter example is based on the case that probability of skewed rectangles is more than one whose shapes are close to square . But in the question, it is said that all rectangles are equally likely. So all rectangles are possible along with their flip versions

Comment: @sanket "All rectangles being equally likely" usually means uniform distribution, but that's impossible because the range of parameter in the family is always unbounded. The only ways to paremeterize it that come to mind are using the ratio (like I did), the height, width or even perimeter, but all of those range to $+\infty$, so there are no uniform distribution. If you didn't mean uniform distribution, you'll have to be more specific.

Comment: I agree that it is uniform distribution but my concern is in the assumption that you took to show the counter example. We cannot have a case when skewed rectangles occur more than the square-like rectangles. For both type, chances are same. Thus, your assumption for counter example, seems to be not true.  We can set some restriction on width or height that it cannot be more than this and consider all rectangles from width 0 to the threshold width. But have to consider all rectangles in that range.

Comment: @sanket In an arbitrary distribution you can have anything you want. Simply the assumption of having a rectangle occur as frequently as its inverse ratio rectangle don't prevent you from having more "skewed" rectangles than "square" rectangle. If you limit the width range, it has to be from some max width $W$ down to its inverse inverse $1/W$. If you take uniform distribution on that, the property is then most likely true.

Comment: @sanket I've made another edit for the "uniform" distribution.

Comment: could you please explain on how we get the equation for  s(ρ) that represents the uniform distribution in the curvilinear abscissa.

Comment: @sanket Edited. This made me notice I had made a mistake in the constant factor of $s(\rho)$, but this has no consequence on the later parts. Changed to the proper constant for consistency.

Comment: Thanks.. you mentioned that corner of the rectangle traces a portion of hyperbola. is it an assumption or some property that it really traces path of hyperbola?

Comment: Also, could you please let me know how did you write first line of E[overlap] in terms of (f(s,s0) /s_max) ds  . I am not able to understand this expectation definition.

Comment: @sanket I remembered why I had a different constant first time I wrote this... too lazy to change it back again, but it still doesn't change the result. Assume the lower left corner is the origin of axis, the top right corner then has coordinates $(w,h)=(w,A/w)$, that's a hyperbola. In the post I just expressed it in terms of $\rho$, and it's also apparent it is a hyperbola if you take $\sqrt\rho$ as a variable. For the expectation, it's just the integral of $f(s,s_0)\operatorname{pdf}(s)\,ds$, which is the usual definition of an expectation.

Comment: Simply, $f(s,s_0)$ would be the area of overlap when expressed in terms of the curvilinear abscissa, and because the distribution is uniform over $s$ it reduces to $1/(s_\text{max}-s_\text{min})$, and $s_\text{min}$ is null.

Comment: In "the pdf" section,  you mentioned,  ρ2pdf(ρ)=pdf(1/ρ)ρ2pdf⁡(ρ)=pdf⁡(1/ρ) , I was trying to understand how it is concluded but couldn't get it. If it is by equating content under integrals, i think we cannot do that. Please suggest

Comment: @sanket I'm surprised you're still on this! In general you're right, you cannot directly equate the content under the integrals, but don't forget the equality is true for every pair of $\rho_1,\rho_2$ values. Let $$f(a,b)=\int_a^b\left(\text{pdf}(t)-\frac{\text{pdf}(1/t)}{t^2}\right)\,dt$$, it is constant equal to $0$ so its partial derivative wrt $b$ is also $0$. From that we deduce that the integrand is a constant function. Then $f(a,b)=(b-a)\times$constant$=0$, from which we deduce the constant must be $0$, so the integrand is constant equal to $0$.